# I want to create a costing table for when various options are selected in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have created a table for the price of the different option combinations but want to show the total cost on a simple input table.
So I want to select from 3 different option groups in separate columns (venue, time period & support).  I have drop down lists for each of choices within these options and the prices associated with each.  I want to show the cost if I choose venue option 1 in column C, time period option 2 in Column D and support Option 3 in Column E.  I have tried the formula =if(and(C3=I2,D3=K1,E3=J3),K3) which works to give me one cost with one range of selections but how do I add more selections to the Formula.  (I moved the 'look up' table onto the same tab so it was easier to read which is why the formula is showing the sheet ref.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using index & match with two data validation lists like this:

[image]

Here is the formula used in cell F8 so you can copy it:

```
=INDEX($L$2:$M$4,MATCH(F2,$K$2:$K$4,0),MATCH(G2,$L$1:$M$1,0))
```

I would consider re-jigging the data so that a third data validation controls which data set is relevant. The choose function can work for that as well.

F2 and G2 are data validation selecting service level and time.

Edit: Version with choose to select data:
[image]

Added a vlookup to give an indexing number for the choose function and the choose to get the data from the list based on which is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response however it will not allow me to use the options that I need.  Could you advise me if i wanted to create multiple if formula's how would this be constructed? =if(and(C3=I2,D3=K1,E3=J3),K3),or(=if(and(C3=I2,D3=K1,E3=J4),K4)

Comment: As I pointed out you can have a selected data set which is based on the choice of hire space. I wasn't about to type in all your data just to give a full solution - I thought showing you the technique would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, sorry didn't mean to sound ungrateful, i was trying to keep it within my knowledge level as I am on a time limit to get a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike,  So I have used the index formula you provide to get the same as above but you mentioned using the choose function to get the 3rd data control, how would that be incorporated into the formula?  Thanks

Comment: @AmandaThacker see version 2, just did 1 column but you can expand it as needed. Choose is used to collect the 'correct" set of data into those cells K2:M4. But that is not the only way to lay it out, just the one that came to me at first glance...

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated and have learnt something new.

Comment: @AmandaThacker if it helped then either vote for it or accept it with the check mark. Thanks.